# Вывод страниц и под страниц в WP

Tags: wordpress

Задача вывести список под страниц и под под страниц :)

Если с под страницами нет проблем, то с другими возникает небольшая проблема.

Есть функция

```
function devise_list_child_pages() {

global $post;

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;
}
```

Она выводит вот так

```
Под страница
  под под страница
  под под страница
Под страница
  под под страница
  под под страница
```

Все хорошо, но если перейти по ссылке "под под страница", то выведется только одна ссылка.

[image]

После клика на "Проходную печь" выводит только ее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы постоянно выводился первый вариант?

Comment: Первые вариант это что, список всех страниц с самой верхней?

Comment: @KAGGDesign нет, первый страницы будут выводиться в хедере, в сайд баре мне нужно выводить под страницы и под под страницы.